# XQuery: generate a variable name from string (attribute value)

Tags: xquery

I have a framework which runs my xquery and it includes an XML config file that defines the parameters I can use in the query as variables, like this:

```
<text name="myVar" label="My Var"/>
```

This means that the user will have a dialog with a field called "My Var", whose value I can then access as `$myVar` in my query. I don't know how the variable is declared and have no access to the XQuery code that runs my query.

But I want to access my params in a generic way, e.g. go through all of them, check if empty, create a table with labels and values in HTML. I do have access to the XML config file. That means I have to access the value of

```
$(/config/text/@name)
```

(The above does not work obviously).

How is it possible?

Comment: Can you provide some additional context or show some more code from that module, and what XQuery engine your are using (Saxon, BaseX, MarkLogic, etc)?

Comment: My query forms a part of a generated XQuery, that is then run over Marklogic that stores CMS data. The CMS has a lot of configuration in XML form that I can access (in addition to the collections that I actually need to query), and one of these is used by the Java module that generates the XQY into which my own query is then embedded (actually a snippet of XQuery code that is not complete in itself; all of the namespaces, imports, external var definitions are generated for it at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Well, variable names such as `$myVar` can only be defined statically, so this isn't going to be possible unless you actually generate the source code of your query programmatically from what you find in the config file.

I think what I would do here is to pass the parameters as a map:

```
declare variable $params as map(xs:string, item()*);
do-something-with($params('myVar'));
```

The entries in the map can be accessed either statically `($params?myVar)` or dynamically `($params('myVar'))`

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I guess the vars themselves are generated in the way you suggest by the code that runs my query. It reads the config, generates an XQuery with the external variables named accordingly, sets them to the values given by the user and then embeds my query into it and runs the whole shebang. So there is no way to go in the other direction either? I mean, get the variable name as a string from the variable itself? (I realize that this sounds like absolute nonsense, but I've seen wonderful things in the XML world).

Comment: No, sorry, variable names aren't available in any way at query execution time. (Unlike function names, which in XQ 3.0 are!)

Comment: Well, good to know. I guess I'll have to resort to, ahem, thinking of something.